# Configuring and Activating a Belkin USB wireless adapter on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, usb, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I'm trying to configure my wireless adapter for use on my Ubuntu machine. I had this particular configuration working before on Ubuntu 14.04, however after updating, the same methods I used to get it to work previously are no longer working. I would prefer ethernet interface, however a power surge fried the ethernet port.

I've installed ndiswrapper and wpa_supplicant. I followed the advice from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623048/help-with-belkin-dual-band-wireless-adapter-ac867), and that worked for me in 14.04, however it no longer works. When running dmesg, I find this particular entry:

`rtl8812au 1-4:1.0 wlxec1a595e9c03: renamed from wlan0`

I also find this entry:

`8812au: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`

Running iwconfig, I find something that indicates that my wifi interface is in some way configured, but very incorrectly:

```
wlxec1a595e9c03 unassociated Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEX>"
    Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz Access Point: Not-Associated
    Sensitivity:0/0
    Retry:off   RTS thr:off    Fragment thr:off
    Power Management:off
    Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
    Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
    Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

The adapter I'm using is, based on `lsusb` is:

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 050d:1109 Belkin Components F9L1109v1 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]`

I'm fairly new to unix systems, and have just under a year of experience.

Does anyone have any advice on what I might do get this interface up? Otherwise, my server will remain down. If there is not a known fix, can anyone recommend a good ethernet to usb adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered my problem. There were some discrepancies in the interface name in my /etc/network/interfaces file. Fixing those, restarting wpa_supplicant, and then bringing up the interface allowed me to successfully connect to the internet.